# Homebrew: How-To forbid a specific package to be installed?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

Can I configure `brew` to never install a specific package even if it is required by another package I install?

I do not want to accidentally install any software that has a dependency on Java, i.e. Java Development Kid (JDK) and Java Runtime Environment (JRE). For me personally, Java is a security risk.

The brew package `dependency-check` automatically installs Java stuff as a dependency.

```
brew install dependency-check
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/dependency-check/manifests/9.0.9
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Fetching dependencies for dependency-check: openjdk
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/manifests/21.0.2
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Fetching openjdk
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/blobs/sha256:9850be1875b9df8e9fa3510b6f2e947be2ff228d64a1c8e0daebc57a018ce2ef
######################################################                                                                                                                                                                             24.3%##########################################################                                                                                                                                                                         26.2%#############################################################                                                                                                                                                                      27.5%################################################################                                                                                                                                                                   28.8%###################################################################                                                                                                                                                                30.1%##################################################################################
```

Solution for Debian based systems: [How to forbid a specific package to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the package installation to fail if they rely on `openjdk`. One way to solve this is to use a custom function to install Homebrew packages and check the dependencies of a formula first.

```bash
function brew_install() {
    [[ "$1" ]] || exit 1

    if brew deps "$1" | grep -q jdk; then
        echo "$1 depends on Java, aborting"
        exit 1
    fi

    brew install "$1"
}
```

PS: You may need to adjust the pattern used by `grep` to include all the relevant packages (and avoid false positives).